# Argon 2 library use in android

Tags: android, c, argon2-ffi

I dont have any knowledge of using c libraries, i need to use Argon2 library https://github.com/p-h-c/phc-winner-argon2 in my android application, i read alot of articles about adding c code into android app, but i cannot find the .so file of the library, i tried opening the library in visual studio to build but no luck. i tried to use the make command in cmd windows but no luck, is it possible to add the c code directly into my android app with out the need to build, or i must build an os? i am using a mac computer for my android development.

if possible, please guid me into doing it, note that we need to add same library to our ios app and c# website and server.

thank you in advance